# API security: how to secure refresh token api's

Tags: android, api, security, express, authentication

I have two api's used in `auth`

1)api/auth/newtoken

Successfully validates user (ie username and password check in DB) and return `token`(expir:3 days) and `refreshToken`.

1)api/auth/updatetoken

when the token is expired call this api with `refreshToken` and get the new `token`.

My question is how can i protect `api/auth/updatetoken` api ? currenlty this api's are for an android application and it will easy to get this api's once we decomplile the application .

What are some better approach to secure this api??

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about? I assume you'll be verifying that the `refreshToken` and `token` are valid, so why is it a concern if someone decompiles your application and learns about this endpoint? A discussion of the security of something should also consider the threat model (what risks are you concerned about, who the attackers would be, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Save the device id then for refresh you can check if the device id submitted is correct or not, if necessary use IP too